# Is there any common fix for jQuery Firefox error: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0?

Tags: jquery

I updated jQuery latest version v1.4.2 and getting 'Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0' this error. Is the any common fix for this. I found some solution and they are saying that when finding dimension for display none element it will give this error. Also the following fix is working for me

Placing this

```
if (!elem || elem == document) elem = document.body
```

above this line

```
var computedStyle = defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null);
```

I am not sure this is the proper solution. I first found this bug when using jquery blockUI plugin and after updating that plugin to latest version fixed this issue. Anyone suggest me better solution for this?

Comment: Am I misreading, or is the only problem that an out-of-date plugin doesn't work with the latest jQuery release?

Comment: So the problem is fixed? No, I can't do better than that.

Comment: In the case of blockUI the problem fixed by placing the above dirty fix code in jQuery core or upgrading the blockUI plugin. But any jQuery experts suggest me the better solution so it will work for all plugins without upgrading. Also I think it is not good to do dirty quick fixes in jQuery latest version v1.4.2